# How do ActiveSheet, ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet and Application.ActiveSheet behave differently?

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I am in the habit of of always using `ActiveSheet` like this: `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`.  I recently stumbled across [this Microsoft page](http://Application.ActiveSheet%20Property) with code that includes `ActiveSheet` without `ActiveWorkbook`.  The title of that page is `Application.ActiveSheet` Property.

Is there a difference between these three lines of code?

```
ActiveSheet
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Application.ActiveSheet
```

Comment: In a sense, there's no difference, all of them are source of bad code, bugs and head aches. Best thing is to forget them altogether. Technically, they refer to the same object, but when driving Excel from another application, it's important to qualify, like `xlApp.ActiveSheet`.

Comment: The `ActiveWorkbook` refers to the top most Excel window. `ActiveSheet` is the selected sheet in the referenced workbook. The last two are equivalent **IF** there is only one workbook open.

Comment: @Kevin is it possible that the active sheet does not belong to the active workbook?

Comment: @A.S.H, what if the code is always run exclusively from Excel?

Comment: ChrisB In that case I've never thought of any difference between them.

Comment: @A.S.H, I think it may depend on the context of where the active sheet is referenced. Probably not a good idea to use just a bare `ActiveSheet`, just as a precaution.

Comment: @Kevin ah, I see what you mean, it differs if that code in written inside some workbook code module. Excellent catch. You should post it as an answer I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These all refer to the same thing *the active sheet*, but the context may not be as expected. `ActiveSheet` is the least restrictive and refers to whatever the 'current' Workbook may be. 
`ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` just makes it a little more clear. Contrast this with `Thisworkbook` which is the workbook where the code is running.
`Application.ActiveSheet` refers to **either** the active workbook or the named workbook / window.
If you have more than one workbook open, it is always best to be explicit about the object you are referring to.

Important note: When alone and written in the code module `ThisWorkbook` of some workbook, `ActiveSheet` differs from both `Application.ActiveSheet` and from `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` (which are always the same). In this special case, `ActiveSheet` refers to `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` even if `ThisWorkbook` is not the active workbook of the Excel application.

Comment: That's helpful.  Thanks @Kevin!

Comment: What about `Excel.Activesheet`?  Does that refer to the same object as `Application.Activesheet` when run from Excel?

Comment: @ChrisB As far as I can tell these are the same thing.