# Example of Activate() function in Visual Studio VB Ribbon Designer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, ribbon

I have researched to death and am really stuck. I am using Visual Studio 2017 to develop an excel ribbon. How do I get it to refer to the active sheet? I do see the Activate() function but no examples of how it is used and I have tried a few things now. I just need an example and I can be on my way.

Comment: Does [How do ActiveSheet, ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet and Application.ActiveSheet behave differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45024774/1115360) cover it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?